# Capture list of targets after cue

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create an expression that will retrieve a target or list of targets after a cue. I can currently get the first one, but I seem to be doing something wrong to get the repetitions. This is what I have so far:

```
import regex

text = "Some text cue: target, target, target and target. Other text."

expression = regex.compile(
fr"""
(?:cue)  # cue before targets. non capture (?:)
(?:.*?)  # text before the match. non capture (?:), as short as possible (?)
(target)
""",
re.VERBOSE,
)

matches = regex.findall(
    expression,
    text,
    overlapped=True,
)
```

I have tried `(target,\s)*` but that is not working.

(Note that the real-use case will be more involved, where targets are actually a collection of strings, etc.)

The ideal output should be:

```
["target", "target", "target", "target"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import regex

text = "Some text cue: target, target, target and target. Other text."

expression = regex.compile(fr"""
cue:  # cue before targets
(?:\s*(?:(?:,|\band\b)\s*)?(?P<targets>target))+
""",
regex.VERBOSE,
)

match = regex.search(expression, text)
if match:
    print( match.captures("targets") )

# => ['target', 'target', 'target', 'target']
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##XY5Ba8MwDIXv@hXCu9ibyaW3sC0w6LmlhZ1ycTylMSyxsVVIof89c52wwYTRs8Xz9xRuPPhptyxuDD4yRrrQDMA0M76hOPuRsDzslWpkEy/E@p@imb62a4UHHiiWL5UAoDlESsn5KdMKu7J@DO6bZB@FEFCw@PTAY0e9j7SREsimbtNz7vnoe9vllLZTeaQa2RxfN9v7qkq9QOZpWEM@96ePw3mvQQGMhu3wG5/IRDvIv8V0WVaB67E4a8BcIbqJ5TqprAl8zXYptlChUC3LDw).

The `cue:(?:\s*(?:(?:,|\band\b)\s*)?(?P<targets>target))+` regex matches

- `cue:` - a string
- `(?:\s*(?:(?:,|\band\b)\s*)?(?P<targets>target))+` - one or more sequences of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:(?:,|\band\b)\s*)?` - an optional sequence of a comma or a whole word `and` followed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?P<targets>target)` - Group "targets" matching `target`